# Unknown MPI_Datatype in MPI_Get_count

Tags: c++, mpi, c++14, openmpi

I want to send several instances of `struct S` to some processes. The layout of each `struct` could be different, that is, `s.v` might have different sizes. When receiving data, I do not know the exact `MPI_Datatype` in `MPI_Get_count` because that information is available in  the sender process only. Also consider that `struct S` has a lot of non-primitive members so that I cannot assume the `MPI_Datatype` as `MPI_INT` when receiving. How can I acquire the `MPI_Datatype` to be used for `MPI_Get_count`?

```
struct S
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    MPI_Datatype mpi_dtype;
    void make_layout()
    {        
        const int nblock = 1;    
        int block_count[nblock] = {v.size()};
        MPI_Aint offset[nblock];
        MPI_Get_address(&v[0], &offset[0]);
        MPI_Datatype block_type[nblock] = {MPI_INT};    
        MPI_Type_struct(nblock, block_count, offset, block_type, &mpi_dtype);
        MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_dtype);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        S s0;
        s0.v.resize(7);
        s0.make.layout();
        MPI_Send(MPI_BOTTOM, 1, s0.mpi_dtype, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else
    {
        S s1; // note that right now s1.mpi_dtype != s0.mpi_dtype
        MPI_Status status;
        int number_amount;
        MPI_Probe(0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        // MPI_Get_count(&status, ???, &number_amount);
        // MPI_Recv(...);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MPI messages are generally typeless, that is, they do not carry the datatypes in them. There is no way on the receiver side to obtain detailed information about the message structure. A viable option is to send the structure as two messages. The first one will contain some kind of description, e.g., the length of each vector. Once received, that information is used by the receiver to prepare the data object and to construct the appropriate datatype. Then, the second message will transmit the actual data. Boost.MPI completely automates this process - check its source code to learn how.

Another option is to pack the description with the data in a single message using `MPI_Pack`. On the receiver side, the message size could be probed with type `MPI_PACKED` and the data should be unpacked using `MPI_Unpack`. I don't think the added complexity of this case will offset the small performance loss due to sending two messages instead of one.

In your case that is not necessary as your structure has a single member, which is a vector of integers. Therefore, the correct type to give to `MPI_Get_count` is `MPI_INT`.